# Apache virtual hosts. Reach files at IP/<directoryname>

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm hoping someone can help me with some Apache virtual host config.  I can reach the Apache 'It Works!' page at a particular WAN IP.

I have set up a virtual host for stuart.com via /etc/apache2/sites-available/stuart.com.conf.  I've edited my local hosts file so that when I go to stuart.com I successfully reach the files located in /var/www/stuart.com/public_html.  However I want other people to be able to access these files via WANIP/stuart.com but currently when I do this I get a 404.

My stuart.com.conf files looks like this.  Can anyone advise how I might edit it (or other Apache config) in order to be able to reach the files via WANIP/stuart.com?  I've looked at a number of SO questions related to name based virtual hosts but not found anything that helped me solve this issue

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin stuart.brown@example.co.uk
    ServerName stuart.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/stuart.com/public_html
    Alias /stuart.com "/var/www/stuart.com/public_html"
    <Directory "/var/www/stuart.com/public_html">
            Options None
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: While what you want to achieve is not impossible, it is a little bit difficult (and counter-intuitive). Why do you not want the users to simply access the web-pages over WAN-IP itself? Why create a dummy `stuart.com` path?

Comment: Thanks @hjpotter92 I was curious really as to why I can edit my PCs hosts file to point stuart.com to the WAN IP and I can just enter stuart.com in address bar and access the files at /var/www/stuart.com/public_html yet I can't put WANIP/stuart.com into the address bar and get there.

Comment: You'll have to change/tweak the router's configurations so that other users would also get directed to your WANIP when visiting `stuart.com`.